# Prove two convex sets are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, convex-analysis

> Prove that following two sets are equal:
>   $$
> \operatorname{conv}\left\{\, xx^T \,\middle|\, x\in\Bbb R^n, \|x\|=1 \,\right\} = \left\{ A \in S_n^+ \,\middle|\, \operatorname{Tr}(A)=1 \,\right\},
> $$
>   where $S_n^+$ is the set of all positive-semidefinite matrices.

I already proved that second one contains the first (it is quite easy), but I have no idea how to prove that every positive-semidefinite matrix is the weighted sum of outer products.

Comment: Can't you somehow relate the two sets via the fact that the sum of the eigenvalues of a matrix is equal to its trace?

Comment: @StanTendijck i solved the problem, thank you

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: I have to say it was just a guess (started really thinking about it just now) and I now have to say the exercise is quite nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every symmetric matrix can be decomposed as follows:
$$
{\displaystyle A=Q\Lambda Q^{\textsf {T}}},
$$

where $\Lambda$ is diagonal

We can construct a diagonal matrix from outer products easily, taking vectors with only one non-zero entry of 1 and coefs as diagonal entries of the matrix. Then we just insert $Q$ and $Q^{\textsf {T}}$ into the sum and get the weighted sum of outer products.